# Simple explanation of how mass terms act, in the Standard Model

Tags: mass, standard-model, gauge-theory, fermions, yang-mills

I'm interested to understand a bit better, how mass terms work in the Standard Model.

Examples of the areas I'd like some kind of better understanding, to give an idea of the level of understanding I'm hoping for, are:

- why exactly did physicists believe it impossible for mass to have been a prior given property, without breaking gauge invariant theory or Yang Mills?
- I've heard that a mass term requires left and right handed terms, but that such terms behave like mass, but what are the implications of these statements and why is that so?
- I've also heard that mass terms "flip chirality" (or have to change chirality), but what does that mean in lay terms, why is that so and what does that imply about how mass behaves? What should I understand by that?
- how do we know that such terms do represent mass, or behave like it?  Could other types of term have represented mass or is there something about such terms that makes them unique and necessary as the signifiers for massive particles?

I can appreciate the gist of simple formulae, but I hope for a more accessible explanation since I suspect I wont gain much better understandings from a solely mathematical exposition.

Comment: It would be useful if you tell us something about your level of understanding of physics, so that people don't start writing long answers that you may find trivial or don't understand at all.

Comment: I've tried, by illustrative questions of what I don't get, and some sense how I am on mathematical aspects. I don't honestly know how to qualitatively describe my knowledge, except that way.  I'm more after descriptive/qualitative I guess, with some maths if appropriate to illustrate, rather than primarily maths.

Comment: That doesn’t help. What is your level of physics/mathematics education? Also, “I have heard” isn’t very much liked on this site. Where did you hear it? Can you give a reference?

Comment: UK A level both (no university level study). And, previous reading of answers on this site and popular science sites in particle physics. I can't remember which specific ones, its knowledge absorbed over time, but never really understood beyond that's how particle physicists and those with such knowledge have described it.  But as UK A level physics/maths doesn't go into operators and operator theory, or much of quantum theory at all, I don't have the background for more than layperson comprehension.

Comment: These things really can't be explained without the math, but I applaud your desire to understand, so I'll offer some comments to try to help clarify what I think you're asking. Your first question about mass versus gauge invariance seems to be about the Standard Model, which doesn't have any explicit mass terms for the elementary fermions (quarks and leptons). I'd recommend saving that question for later, and focusing for now on the other question(s) about mass involving left/right handed terms. That subject is normally first learned from the Dirac equation.

Comment: The Dirac equation is an equation describing the time-dependence of a non-interacting fermion (actually the corresponding field operator), but you can learn a lot about the equation's structure without understanding exactly what it means physically yet, and I would actually recommend that approach in this case.  Are you comfortable with matrices and partial derivatives? If you are, then you're well-equipped to learn how the Dirac equation answers your question(s) about mass involving left/right handed terms, and I'd be happy to post an answer about that. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: (I would just post a link to a good introduction, but writing an answer is actually less time-consuming than finding a good introduction among the sea of not-so-good introductions out there. Most of them make things way more complicated than necessary.)

Comment: Thanks very much indeed and YES. Sounds perfect for what im hoping for. As long as I'm guided/walked through the salient points of said equations, what to look for, I'll probably be fine with PDEs and matrices. I kind of lost my way somewhere beyond that, around eigenthings, tensors, operator notation, and groups - the words and definitions made sense but I couldn't get my head round to the point of grokking them and having intuitive sense and understandings of how to work with them. (Sorry for geeky term but its the best way to explain it!) - and QM/QFT/SR are fundamentally built on those.

Comment: Hence why I struggled to understand so far. Taking it a little more on faith and PDE/matrices though, I can probably handle fine with a hint or 2 and some narrative around them.